# Названия болезней

Tags: этимология

Названия таких страшных болезней, как оспа, холера, чума, являются ли они русскими? И, если да, то каково их происхождение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Фасмера можно найти следующие сведения.

**Оспа.** Ср.: др.-русск., ст.-слав. *осъпа*. Праслав. *о-sър-а от* сыпать*, ст.-слав.* съпѪ, соути*.

Название **'Холера'** заимствовано из греч. χολέρα от χόλος, χολή "желчь". В русск. язык слово, возможно, пришло через польск. сhоlеrа, лат. сhоlеrа.

**Чума**. Ср.: укр. чума, джума, блр. чума, ср.-болг. чума "прыщ, нарыв", болг. чума, польск. dżuma. Судя по наличию dј, слово, должно быть, заимствовано. Источником считают тур. čumа с тем же значением.